# JSON passing as a null to a method argument

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, json, knockout.js

I finally tried to try my hand at using KnockoutJS. I explored for shorter ways to send JSON data to a C# method in MVC 4, but ended up using the AJAX method instead. I have some confusion around the following and was hoping someone could help.

**Javascript**

```
var VM = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.ValidateAndCreate = function () {
        console.log("entered");
        var a = {
            b: "1",
            c: "2",
            d: {
                e: "3"
            }
        };
        var input = { data: a }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(input));
        $.ajax({
            url: '/McAfee/ValidateAndCreatePartner',
            data: JSON.stringify(input),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
    }
}
var viewModel = new VM();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**C#**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void ValidateAndCreatePartner(string data)
    {
        var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
        RedirectIfSuccess();
    }
```

What currently happens is that the `ValidateAndCreatePartner` fires, but the argument `data` is null, followed by `NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` failing as a result. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I haven't done anything with JSON for over a year, I also don't have access to my old source code - I feel I am missing something fundamental

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way in MVC is to create class as per your data : it is much cleaner! For example, with your example, you can try this :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(TestClass data) {
    RedirectIfSuccess();
}


public class TestClass
{
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
    public TestSubClass d { get; set; }
}

public class TestSubClass
{
    public int e { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I am an idiot, if you saw my last message. It serialized. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since your content type is `application/json`, the argument to the view function will be automatically deserialized (it's not a string anymore).

Create a viewmodel on the server side matching the one you send and use it as the type argument of the view:

```
public class D {
    public string e {get;set;}
}

public class A {
    public string b {get;set;}
    public string c {get;set;}
    public D d {get;set;}
}   


[HttpPost]
public void ValidateAndCreatePartner(A data)
{
    // no need to deserialize data
    RedirectIfSuccess();
}
```

Comment: Honestly? That's amazing. Gonna try that out on the fly now

Comment: Exactly and as I mentioned in my answer you can also map your integer with `int` types (see `e`).

Comment: Invalid JSON primitive: b.

That is the result I get. Any ideas?